# Load div with jquery allowing only one rady to be check at ones

Tags: jquery

I have this code which allows me to load a content into a div from a Radio Input. The problem is that it allows multiple options to be checked at once, and I need only one option to be checked at once.

```
<form id="filterproducts" action="" method="get">   <div id="filters">
<label><input type="radio" name="hotel" value="hotel" />Hotel</label><br />
<label><input type="radio" name="casa" value="casa" />casa</label><br />
<label><input type="radio" name="otros" value="otros" />otros lugares</label><br />
</p>
</div></form>
<div id="products"></div> 
<script>  
$(':radio').change(function() {
var colour = $(this).val();
$("#products").load("index.php?type="+colour);   }); </script>
```

Answer (score 3):

In order for radio buttons to act as a group, you have to specify the same `name` attribute. This will ensure that all radios within the same name act as one radio group, and only one can be selected at once:

```
<label><input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="hotel" />Hotel</label><br />
<label><input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="casa" />casa</label><br />
<label><input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="otros" />otros lugares</label><br />
```

Change `myRadio` with whatever suits you

Comment: @user3373983 Glad it worked. You might consider marking your questions as resolved by selecting a correct answer, so that others searching for the same problem don't have to ask it again.

Answer (score 0):

Apply same name to all radio buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Your radio inputs need to have the same name in order to be able to select only one.

```
<label><input type="radio" name="lugar" value="hotel" />Hotel</label><br />
<label><input type="radio" name="lugar" value="casa" />casa</label><br />
<label><input type="radio" name="lugar" value="otros" />otros lugares</label><br />
```

Answer (score 0):

change your html to set all radio to same name. Then it will select only one at a time.you will have different values for each redio selected.

like this:

```
<form id="filterproducts" action="" method="get">   <div id="filters">
<label><input type="radio" name="name" value="hotel" />Hotel</label><br />
<label><input type="radio" name="name" value="casa" />casa</label><br />
<label><input type="radio" name="name" value="otros" />otros lugares</label><br />
</p>
</div></form>
```

[live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a6NJk/691/)